# Building Discord bot to post tweets in realtime (using discord.py and tweepy), program freezes

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, python-asyncio, tweepy

I'm trying to build a discord bot that sends new twitter posts into chat (in realtime). Not all that familiar to async yet, and with minimal examples available I'm still kind of lost.

I have two classes, `twitterClient` and `discordClient`, and I pass the message sending function and the event loop to the `twitterClient`. I then call `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` to run the message sending function when the twitterClient receives a tweet.

When I run this and post a tweet, the program seems to receive the tweet (as shown by the print statement) but the program doesn't get any further. Since `ctrl-c` doesn't work after this step, it seems to me that the program freezes there. What should I do? Am I even using asyncio correctly?

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import tweepy
import asyncio

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
GUILD = os.getenv('DISCORD_GUILD')
BEARER = os.getenv('TWITTER_BEARER_TOKEN')

rule = {'fromknowgnod':'from:knowgnod'}

class twitterClient(tweepy.StreamingClient):
    def __init__(self, send, loop, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.loop = loop
        self.send = send

    def on_connect(self):
        print('connected to stream')
        # check if rule already uploaded
        api_rule_tags = [i.tag for i in self.get_rules().data]
        if list(rule.keys())[0] not in api_rule_tags:
            self.add_rule(value=rule[list(rule.keys())[0]], tag=list(rule.keys())[0])

    def on_tweet(self, tweet):
        print("received tweet: "+str(tweet.id))
        a = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.send(tweet.id), self.loop)
        a.result()

    def on_errors(self, errors):
        print(f"Received error code {errors}")
        self.disconnect()
        return False

class discordClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f'Logged on as {self.user}!')
        myStream = twitterClient(self.send_message, asyncio.get_event_loop(), BEARER)
        myStream.filter()

    async def send_message(self, msg):
        c = self.get_channel(1003516355003289694)
        c.send(f'https://twitter.com/knowgnod/status/{msg}')

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.messages = True
client = discordClient(intents=intents)
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: as I know `tweepy` and `discord.py` need to run loop - and one loop can block another look - and this may need to run one of them in separated thread.

Comment: You probably have to run these in different threads because tweepy doesn't have asyncio support.